# want to save js variable into db which is created on the base of column id

Tags: javascript, php

#markers have json output frm this dynamic datasetid is getting at a checkbox click ,and i am creating a imgname iconUrl with the help of `markerimg=datasetid%10`. i want to save this img name into database ..i am unable to send this iconUrl variable into a php variable.

```
function markerdata(Data)
         {
         # markers =Data;#

          //alert(markers);
          //console.log(markers);
        var json = JSON.parse(markers);

                    var xyz=json["aa"];

         for (var i = 0; i < xyz.length; i++) {


          var mainindex=xyz[i].length;
          for (var j=0;j<mainindex;j++)
          {
          newlat=(xyz[i][j].latitude);
             newlong=(xyz[i][j].longitude);
              newlocation=(xyz[i][j].location);

             id=(xyz[i][j].id);
             datasetid=(xyz[i][j].dataset_id);
         ----------------------------------------
             markerimg=datasetid%10;
         ----------------------------------------
              var location = new L.LatLng(newlat, newlong);
            if (newlocation.length > 0) {
              var address = "<div style='font-size: 14px;'>"+ newlocation +"</div>";
            }
            else {
              var address = "";
            }
            var leafIcon = L.icon({
                                    iconUrl: "markerimg/marker"+ markerimg +".png",
                                    ------------------------------------------------------

                                 });
             var marker = new L.Marker(location, {
              title: address,
              icon: leafIcon
            });

            //console.log(xyz[i][j].location);
            //document.getElementById("address").value = address;
              var form =  '<form id="inputform" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="well">'+
          '<label><strong>location:</strong></label>'+
              '<input type="text" class="span3"  id="address" name="address" value="'+xyz[i][j].location+'"/>'+
              '<input style="display: none;" type="text" id="datasetid" name="datasetid" value="'+datasetid +'" />'+
              '<input style="display: none;" type="text" id="id" name=id" value="'+id +'" />'+
              '<input style="display: none;" type="text" id="latitude" name="latitude" value="'+newlat +'" />'+
              '<input style="display: none;" type="text" id="longitude" name="longitude" value="'+newlong +'" /><br>'+
              '<div class="row-fluid">'+
                  '<div class="span6" style="text-align:center;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="insertUser()">Submit</button></div>'+
              '</div>'+
              '</form>';

        marker.bindPopup(form).openPopup();
            map.addLayer(marker);

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make global variable do change in code like below

```
var finalicon ="markerimg/marker"+ markerimg +".png";

var leafIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: finalicon,
```

});

**USE finalicon varible and pass it to php it'll surely works**